# Bat file to split row from text file into multiple rows

Tags: batch-file

I have application number along with associated images for that application on every row.

```
58:58123 image.jpg,image2.jpg
58:58456 image4.jpg
```

I want to have csv which will contain unique number and one associated image on every row like

```
123 image.jpg
123 image2.jpg
456 image4.jpg
```

I have already created bat file but it is showing me output as

```
58:58123 image.jpg
58:58123 image2.jpg
58:58456 image4.jpg
```

I want to remove 58:58 from every row.

```
@Echo off&(for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ("transact.txt") do For %%C in (%%B) do Echo(%%A,%%C)>Output.csv
```

Actual Output:

```
58:58123 image.jpg
58:58123 image2.jpg
58:58456 image4.jpg
```

Expected Output:

```
123 image.jpg
123 image2.jpg
456 image4.jpg
```

Comment: Your batch produces a different output than you posted. It's unclear if you want to remove a fixed prefix of `58:58` aka 5 characters or if that changes. Aside from 58000 this will get you nearer `@Echo off&(for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%A in ("transact.txt") do For %%D in (%%C) do Echo(%%B,%%D)>Output.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad practice to put all code into a single line as it is hardly maintainable.

Anyway, your code seem to make an attempt to remove the prefix (like `58`), and it does for sure not return the actual output you describe.

But here is a possible way to do what you want (most probably):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Write to the output file:
> "Output.csv" (
    rem // Read from the input file and split at the first `:`:
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-2* delims=: " %%A in ("transact.txt") do (
        rem // Assign parts behind the first `:` to variables:
        set "NUM=%%B" & set "LIST=%%C"
        rem /* Enable delayed expansion to be able to read a variable
        rem    that is has been written in the same block of code: */
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Remove prefix from number before the file names and then
        rem    provide it in a `for` variable (one loop iteration): */
        for %%D in ("!NUM:*%%A=!") do (
            rem /* Modify list so that spaces in file names are preserved,
            rem    loop through the file names (none must contain `,`!): */
            for %%E in ("!LIST:,=" "!") do (
                rem /* Return one file name after another preceded by the
                rem    pruned number; toggle delayed expansion in order to
                rem    avoid trouble with `!` or `^` in the file names: */
                endlocal
                echo(%%~D %%~E
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

This script makes use of [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) as well as [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).