# Bat file to remove data from text file

Tags: batch-file

I have bat file which split my data from one row into multiple rows as expected but it is taking unnecessary data as well.

Data in txt file-
Data will be in same format as below

```
85:85123,  ,Smith,181215:image.tif,image2.tif,image3.tif
85:85456,  ,Richard,184985:image4.tif,image5.tif
85:85789,  ,Aly,589456:image.tif
```

Output I am getting is:

```
123,
123,smith
123,image.tif
123,image2.tif
123,image3.tif
456,
456,Richard
456,image4.tif
456,image5.tif
789,
789,Aly
789,image.tif
```

Output which i want:

```
123,image.tif
123,image2.tif
123,image3.tif
456,image4.tif
456,image5.tif
789,image.tif
```

I only want unique number with image name on every row but I am getting unique number with one blank value and first name as well.

```
@echo off

> "Output.csv" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-2* delims=: " %%A in ("transact.txt") do (
        set "NUM=%%B" & set "LIST=%%C"
         setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%D in ("!NUM:*%%A=!") do (
            for %%E in ("!LIST:,=" "!") do (
                endlocal
                echo(%%~D %%~E
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: The format of your transact.txt is quite different from the version [aschiplf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811705/6811411) wrote the code for. Add a comma to the delims to get better result. (still with the 18xxxx: in the file names)

Comment: Yes but this will be the new format I will be getting to generate csv.

Comment: Then make at least an attempt to solve the new requirement by yourself. [SO] isn't a script writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 3 minimal changes are necessary, to get your desired output.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\09\09\SO_57856028.cmd
@echo off
> "Output.csv" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4* delims=:, " %%A in ("transact.txt") do (
        set "NUM=%%B" & set "LIST=%%E"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%D in ("!NUM:*%%A=!") do (
            for %%E in ("!LIST:,=" "!") do (
                endlocal
                echo(%%~D,%%~E
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to want to filter out all files whose names are not `image` followed by an optional number and followed by `.tif`, which could be done by inserting a bit of code (see `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
> "Output.csv" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-2* delims=:, " %%A in ("transact.txt") do (
        set "NUM=%%B" & set "LIST=%%C"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%D in ("!NUM:*%%A=!") do (
            for %%E in ("!LIST:,=" "!") do (
                endlocal
                rem // Store several interim values into variables:
                set "ITEM=%%~nE" & set "EXT=%%~xE" & set "NUM=%%~D"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem /* Split file name at first numeric part; the preceding `_` just
                rem    ensures that the part before the first number is not empty,
                rem    because then files like `012image3.tif` became handled wrongly;
                rem    everything up to the first colon `:` becomes removed: */
                for /F "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%I in ("_!ITEM:*:=!") do (
                    endlocal
                    rem /* Ensure that the part behind the first numeric part (`%%J`) is
                    rem    empty, that the name part in front of the number is `image`,
                    rem    and that the file extension is `.tif`: */
                    if "%%J" == "" if /I "%%I" == "_image" if /I "%%~xE" == ".tif" (
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        echo(!NUM!,!ITEM:*:=!!EXT!
                        endlocal
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```